# Universal parser of date from an html page

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime

i want to extract dates published in a website if there is any. Is there any python module to parse date from websites universally. The dates can be in any format and in any location of the body. It can be polluted by html tags too.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

**Installation: pip install dateparser**

**Code:**

```py
import dateparser

print(dateparser.parse('Fri, 12 Dec 2014 10:55:50'))
print(dateparser.parse('1991-05-17'))
print(dateparser.parse('In two months'))
print(dateparser.parse('1484823450'))
print(dateparser.parse('January 12, 2012 10:00 PM EST'))
print(dateparser.parse('Martes 21 de Octubre de 2014'))
print(dateparser.parse('Le 11 Décembre 2014 à 09:00'))
print(dateparser.parse('Martes 21 de Octubre de 2014'))  # Spanish (Tuesday 21 October 2014)
print(dateparser.parse('Le 11 Décembre 2014 à 09:00'))  # French (11 December 2014 at 09:00)
print(dateparser.parse('13 января 2015 г. в 13:34'))  # Russian (13 January 2015 at 13:34)
print(dateparser.parse('1 เดือนตุลาคม 2005, 1:00 AM'))  # Thai (1 October 2005, 1:00 AM)
print(dateparser.parse('yaklaşık 23 saat önce'))  # Turkish (23 hours ago), current time: 12:46
print(dateparser.parse('2小时前'))  # Chinese (2 hours ago), current time: 22:30
```

**Output:**

```
2014-12-12 10:55:50
1991-05-17 00:00:00
2021-11-02 16:30:46.973124
2017-01-19 16:57:30
2012-01-12 22:00:00-05:00
2014-10-21 00:00:00
2014-12-11 09:00:00
2014-10-21 00:00:00
2014-12-11 09:00:00
2015-01-13 13:34:00
2005-10-01 01:00:00
2021-09-01 17:30:47.158997
2021-09-02 14:30:47.162196
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution given. Once the date is extracted this works. But how to find the date from between the html tags by just giving a url as input..
Example.
https://www.seattlesymphony.org/en/concerttickets/calendar/2021-2022/21bar3

https://www.toledosymphony.com/events/2021/09/24/promedica-masterworks/musical-portraits/

https://www.hso.org/concerts/an-innocent-man-the-music-of-billy-joel/

if i give urls of several different websites as input then i must get the dates displayed in the webpage as ouput